# Как показать AlertDialog на экране телефона Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog

Нужно когда удаляется приложение показывать AlertDialog примерно так: [image: Пример]

Я делаю следующим образом
MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

Dialog:

```
class Dialog : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog)

        Dialog()

    }

    fun Dialog() {
        val mDialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null)
        val mBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(mDialogView)
        val mAlertDialog = mBuilder.show()

        mDialogView.okBtn.setOnClickListener {
            mAlertDialog.dismiss()
        }

        mDialogView.cancelBtn.setOnClickListener {
            mAlertDialog.dismiss()
        }

    }
}
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED")) {

            Log.e(" BroadcastReceiver ", "onReceive called " + " PACKAGE_REMOVED ")
            Toast.makeText(context, " onReceive !!!! PACKAGE_REMOVED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            val i = Intent(context, Dialog::class.java)
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i)

        }

        else if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")) {
            Log.e(" BroadcastReceiver ", "onReceive called " + "PACKAGE_ADDED");
            Toast.makeText(context, " onReceive !!!!." + "PACKAGE_ADDED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="20dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_txt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="................................"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/okBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Close"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Dialog"/>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

После удаления какого нибудь приложения, вызывается мое приложение и диалог но выглядит это так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а мне нужно чтобы диалог показывался без activity на фоне.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно сделать чтобы было как на картинке сверху.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете создать для этого действия `Activity` с прозрачным фоном, а ней запустить диалог.

Чтоб создать `Activity` с прозрачным фоном создайте тему:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

И примените этот стиль в `Manifest`:

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
...
</activity>
```

Но вы должны помнить, что это должна быть только одна `Activity` в стеке, иначе вы просто увидите прошлую `Activity`

Comment: Как убедится что в стеке только одна активити? Да высвечивается правильно только пришлось заменить на parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat", но вот проблема если я нажимаю на кнопку и закрываю диалог или нажимаю мимо диалога чтобы он закрылся я остаюсь на прозрачной активити. Можно как-то полностью закрывать прилу, причем не сворачивать а именно закрывать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947916/android-remove-all-the-previous-activities-from-the-back-stack

Comment: Ну вы по закрытию диалога должны вызывать в активити finish(). Еща вам стоит убрать анимации появления/ухода активити

Comment: Да finish() я уже добавил, а про анимацию спасибо за совет